# logrotate deletes 2nd day old file, which should not happen

Tags: logrotate

i need to rotate log files and i am able to do that, but once files are rotated after two day old file is being deleted, i don't want that to happen, below is my config

```
/home/logs/catalina.out {
   su root root
   copytruncate
   notifempty
   daily
   dateext
   dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
   rotate 4
   compress
   missingok
  }
```

Comment: Post the contents of your global config file. I don't know what distribution you're on but it's usually at `/etc/logrotate.conf`